# MPMoviePlayerViewController stops after a few seconds

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, media-player, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have an app in which I am streaming a live TV channel in one of tabs. I am using `MPMoviePlayerViewController`. I did declare my `MPMoviePlayerViewController` in my header file and synthesize it in my implementation file.

Here's my viewDidAppear:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated   
{
    NSURL *movieURL = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://mysuperURL"];
    moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
    [self checkIt];
}
```

And my checkIt function

```
- (void) checkIt {
    if ([[moviePlayerController moviePlayer] loadState] == MPMovieLoadStateUnknown) { // before you wreck yourself
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(checkIt) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    } else {
        [moviePlayerController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
        [self presentModalViewController:moviePlayerController animated:YES];
    }
}
```

**However the video freezes after two seconds and the app stops responding.**

Comment: what checkIt method do ?

Comment: why you have used [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(checkIt) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];?

Comment: checkit method controls whether the movie is in playable state or not. if the movie is not in playable state it waits .1 seconds(nstimer) and re-calls the checkit method again.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the MPMoviePlayerNotifications instead of manually polling the current state.

For example - somewhere in you initializing code:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChange:) 
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification 
                                               object:nil];
```

Now implement a notification handler:

```
- (void)MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(@"loadstate change: %Xh", movieController_.loadState);    
}
```

And somewhere within your deinitializing code:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self 
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification 
                                                  object:nil];
```

Also note that MPMoviePlayerController.loadState is a bitmap -> you need to mask out the value you want to check for.

For Example:

```
if ((movieController_.loadState & MPMovieLoadStatePlayable) == MPMovieLoadStatePlayable)
{
    NSLog(@"yay, it became playable");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Asfar as my knowledge concern usage of timer it is freezing and it takes time streaming also.

Comment: i don't think it is the timer, since i do not push the player to my view with timer. timer just waits the movie to be ready.